# Insert field name in Delphi SQL parameter instead of string

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters

I have written an SQL query in delphi that has a parameter

```
WHERE L1.IdListino = :IdListino
```

Based on some input from the user, I want this parameter to be either a field of a form (tParsIdListinoExport is the name of the field), or a column of another table (something like WHERE L1.IdListino = fat.IdListino).

```
if tParsIdListinoExport.AsString <> '' then
        qSel.ParamByName( 'IdListino' ).AsString := tParsIdListinoExport.AsString
    else
        qSel.ParamByName( 'IdListino' ).Value := 'fat.IdListino';
end;
```

Sadly, looks like I can't insert a column name as a parameter, because it adds the '' around the name of the column, thus treating it as plain text.
Is it possible to remove the '' from the parameter?
Thank you very much,

Fabio

Comment: That's not how parameters work. If you need to do string replacement for field names, use `Format`.

Comment: What @KenWhite says.  Generally, In SQL queries, parameters are placeholders for *values* in *columns*, not placeholders for entity-names, like columns, tables, views etc.

Comment: As Ken states... that is not how parameters work. If the client has a value to use then a parameter is the best way to comunicate it to the server. Parameter values are not burnt into the SQL code, but are passed separately. If you want the server to join and use a value from another table, then you must build a correct SQL statement (without parameters).

Answer (score 3):

You need create your SQL Instruction in runtime, like:

```
with qSel do
begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add(addYourSqlHere, without Where clause);
    if Condition1 then
        SQL.Add('where FIELD1 = :PARAM01')
    else
        SQL.Add('where FIELD2 = :PARAM01');
    ParamByName('PARAM01').Value := UserFilter;
end;
```

Comment: You should change UserFilter to be a parameter to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve what you need with sql.  The details are a little dependent upon the RDBMS but something along the lines of

> where (:param1 = 'use_field' and :param2 = OtherTable.field) or
>         (:param1 = 'use_param' and  Table.field = :param3)

This assumes that `Table` and `OtherTable` are joined.
It also assumes `Param1` can be mentioned more than once - not all databases will allow this.